# Error in seaborn plot " Horizontal orientation requires numeric `x` variable"

Tags: visualization, python, graphs

I am trying to plot a box plot with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) with the following code

```
plot = sns.boxplot(
    y='Min PPI distance',
    x='Synergy_percent',
    color='white',
    orient="h",
    data=synergy_df
)
plot.set(
    xlabel='Synergy (%)',
    ylabel='Min. distance',
);
```

The data `synergy_df` looks like

```
    Combination Min PPI distance    Synergy_percent
0   1003- Camptothecin & 1011- Navitoclax   2.0 22.2
1   1003- Camptothecin & 1017- Olaparib 2.0 6.4
2   1003- Camptothecin & 1022- AZD7762  2.0 40.4
3   1003- Camptothecin & 1025- SB216763 3.0 2.1
4   1003- Camptothecin & 1032- Afatinib 3.0 2.2
```

After running the above code I am getting the error
`` TypeError: Horizontal orientation requires numeric `x` variable. ``
I want to add that Synergy_percent column has many zero values and about 1500 rows; I haven't tried it with a smaller number of rows.

I think the reason for the error is the wide range in the synergy_percent values. The range is between 0 to 86.7. If I use xlim here what range should I use to divide the x-axis in 4 quarters (0-25-50-100)?

**Background** Seaborn is a Python library for more complex graph plotting than the commonly used `matplotlib` and is often used for boxplots and heatmaps usually using a `pandas` dataframe. The official documents are described [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very quickly because I'm not around.

I think I know what's going on, but don't have enough time to figure the df. The key thing is `seaborn` needs to know where columns are `x` and which are `y` ... *within the data frame* . This information appears missing and the OP used `y='title', x='title` without reference to the dataframe. I'm pretty certain thats the bug here.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot = sns.boxplot(
    color='white',
    y=synergy_df["Synergy_percent"], 
    x=synergy_df["Min PPI distance"] 
);
plt.show()
```

Alternative, which seems more what the OP wants ...

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot = sns.boxplot(
    color='white',
    # use your orientation command here
    x=synergy_df["Synergy_percent"], 
    y=synergy_df["Min PPI distance"] 
);
plt.show()
```

**Blurb** Normally the x-axis is the discrete boundary whilst the y-axis is continuous. In you example the x-axis feels like the continuous variable and you are producing a rotated boxplot - thats perfectly fine and seabourn will do that however its  good to get it working first before rotating the axes.

**Final** The orientation of the dataframe might possibly be an issue, not sure unless its tried.

---

If there's a formatting issue the only trick I know is

```
 plot = sis.boxplot(
 .... # same old
 dodge=True,
 );
```

I don't know beyond, e.g. imposing percentile ranges onto a boxplot.

Comment: Well its good its working. Could you try `dodge=True`. ?? What I think you want is to tweak the 'box and whiskers' of the boxplot - which I'd have to look up. The other possibility (which I don't think you want) is to make 4 boxplots within the range specified. This is last point is about `pandas` filtering and would be outside seaborn. I'm pretty certain you just need a simple tweak within `boxplot` method. However, beyond the `dodge` trick I dunno, but `dodge` does clean stuff up.

Comment: Good to know; I guess that means `data=X` doesn't have the same effect in seaborn as it does in R.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with seaborn, but I'd guess from the error that there's at least one text value inside the `Synergy_percent` field that is encouraging the rest of the values to text. Either that, or spaces in the input file are messing up the parsing of the columns.